# Finding the distance between pointers in the same block or array

Tags: c, malloc

If I have a block of memory malloc'd of size `char * a = malloc (10*sizeof(char*))`,
and I have two char pointers, `b` and `c` inside of this block,
how can I find the distance between these two pointers?

If the memory addresses go from `0x00` to, say `a+5`, then 
how could I accurately get the distance between `b` and `c`?

Comment: You mean, `c-b` or `b-c`, depending on which is bigger ?

Comment: "*... two char pointers, b and c inside of this block.*" You mean **pointing to** "*inside*  the block?

Comment: yes pointing to inside the block

Answer (score 0):

If `b` and `c` are your `char*` pointers, point at memory inside of the block `a`, you can just use `c-b` to find the distance between them.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *a = calloc(10, 1);
    a[3] = 'h';
    a[6] = 'i';
    char *b = &a[3];
    char *c = &a[6];

    /* Print out the pointer address. */
    printf("%p\n", b);
    printf("%p\n", c);
    /* Subtracting the pointers gives a long int type. */
    printf("%ld\n", c-b);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives:

```
0xe4b013
0xe4b016
3
```

Obviously the first two are going to change each run but it gets the distance correct, because `calloc` and `malloc` are going to give you a contiguous memory block or fail; it's all right next to each other. They give you the pointer to the first address in that block.

*edit for clarification:*

The pointers have a certain type, which is used in the pointer arithmetic. It's a coincidence that this was asking about `char` pointers and `char` types are only `1` byte long; if the type was something of `20` bytes, the pointer arithmetic would be the same, returning a result of `3`.

It is essentially "how many items *of size pointed to by these pointers* did it move along" and we're calculating the offset, with the number returned being `address_2 - address_1 / size_of_the_type`.

Comment: One might add that the distance is in bytes scaled (divided) by the size of the type the pointers are pointing to. This implies that you cannot substract pointers of different types.